# How on earth are these Functions supposed to be written? There was no example for this specific type. They're mostly arguments

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

This is a part of a course that did not elaborate

> introduction(name)
> 1) takes in an argument of a name and returns a phrase with that name using string interpolation
>
> introductionWithLanguage(name, language)
> 2) takes in two arguments, a name and a language, and returns a phrase using those arguments
>
> introductionWithLanguageOptional(name, language)
> 3) takes in two arguments, a name and a language, and language defaults to JavaScript
>
> introductionWithLanguageOptional(name, language)
> 4) takes in two arguments, a name and a language, and the default value can be overridden with an argument
>
> 0 passing (88ms)
> 4 failing
>
> 1. introduction(name)
>    takes in an argument of a name and returns a phrase with that name using string interpolation:
>    ReferenceError: introduction is not defined
>    at Context. (test/indexTest.js:6:5)
>    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21)
> 2. introductionWithLanguage(name, language)
>    takes in two arguments, a name and a language, and returns a phrase using those arguments:
>    ReferenceError: introductionWithLanguage is not defined
>    at Context. (test/indexTest.js:13:5)
>    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21)
> 3. introductionWithLanguageOptional(name, language)
>    takes in two arguments, a name and a language, and language defaults to JavaScript:
>    ReferenceError: introductionWithLanguageOptional is not defined
>    at Context. (test/indexTest.js:20:5)
>    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21)
> 4. introductionWithLanguageOptional(name, language)
>    takes in two arguments, a name and a language, and the default value can be overridden with an argument:
>    ReferenceError: introductionWithLanguageOptional is not defined
>    at Context. (test/indexTest.js:26:5)
>    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21)

I tried several functions:

```
function logTwoValues(value1, value2) {
  console.log(`The two values are ${value1} and ${value2}.`);
}

function sayHelloTo(firstName) {
  console.log(`Hello, ${firstName}!`);
}
```

Comment: `console.log` is not returning the value.  outputting  and returning are very different things.

Comment: Please attach a code

Comment: so, 2 things. 1) you have to use the function names provided. 2) you have to RETURN a string.

Comment: *"introduction(name)"* — tells you you need to name your function and argument exactly like this — *"1) takes in an argument of a name"* — tells you again that the argument needs to be named "`name`" — *"and returns"* — tells you you need to use a `return` statement — *"a phrase with that name using string interpolation"* — tells you that you're supposed to use string interpolation, and what you're supposed to return (apparently any arbitrary sentence with that name in it).

Comment: *"introduction(name) takes ... ReferenceError: introduction is not defined at Context."* — Tells you that the test is looking for something named "`introduction`" and couldn't find it. Because you failed to follow the first step of the instructions. — It's really all there, even if you need to get used to reading these kinds of instructions and error messages.

Comment: https://github.com/learn-co-curriculum/phase-0-pac-3-function-parameters-lab

Comment: Here is a solution. Note the last (4) is a variations on (3) https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/qmjt7vco/ - I post this to show you the instructions can be followed. Let me know if I pass

Answer (score -1):

You need to return the value from function

```js
function logTwoValues(value1, value2) {
  return `The two values are ${value1} and ${value2}.`;
}

function sayHelloTo(firstName) {
  return `Hello, ${firstName}!`;
}

console.log(sayHelloTo("Stack overflow"));
console.log(logTwoValues("Hello", "world"));
```

Comment: why is your code using `console.log` at all in those functions, it's not a requirement and only serves to further confuse the OP!

Comment: These are the instructions I was given. How am I supposed to write this? There are literally no instructions on how to complete this activity.

Comment: @Noneof This answer literally shows you how you're supposed to do it…!?

Comment: @deceze If the answer showed me how to do it, I would not have an error code to upload on this platform.

Comment: @Noneof Because you also haven't named the function "`introduction`"…

Comment: @Noneofyourbizz Where are you uploading ?